# regex to get the text before email id and hyphen with space

Tags: regex

```
abc Roh-Mint
Stéphanie The
Aud Rohrbach-Minette
ManDesmé - Jdfredac@abc.com
Le san Dunk – Le@le.Fr

^([^ –]*)
```

With the regex used, it takes only first word and not the whole word.

Result should be:

```
abc Roh-Mint
Stéphanie The
Aud Rohrbach-Minette
ManDesmé
Le san Dunk
```

can you please help me with this regex

Comment: If the invalid string is always followed by `-`, [`^.*?(?=\s-|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/eOSIAB/2) could do the job as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple pattern which seems to be working:

```regex
^.*?(?= [-–] \w+@\w+\.\w+|$)
```

### Demo

Explanation:

```
^                      from the start of the line
.*?                    match all content up to, but not including
(?=
    [-–] \w+@\w+\.\w+  a dash followed by an email address
    |                  OR
    $                  the end of the input (for those names sans email address)
)
```

Comment: I was confused about `[-–]` for a moment but realized they are different characters  good thinking

Comment: Thank you so much. But why [--] is used.

Comment: @virgopassionate If you look closely, you will see that you have two types of dashes, one looks to be regular hyphen, the other one maybe is an en-dash or em-dash.

Comment: yeah. Thank you  so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also remove from the first email address to the end of the line.

```
[-–] [^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@].*$
```

**Explanation**

- `[-–]` Match a space, one of the hyphens and space
- `[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]` Match an "email like" format, where `[^\s@]+` is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any character except a whitespace char or `@`
- `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qJl7pe/1)

**Result**

```
abc Roh-Mint
Stéphanie The
Aud Rohrbach-Minette
ManDesmé
Le san Dunk
```